# Java Decimal To Binary - Big Numbers to Binary

Tags: java, binary

My program should convert decimal numbers to binary. For big numbers it is giving me a negative number not a binary number. Why is this?

For example, if I supply `2321` I get `100100010001`, which is fine. But if I supply 
`241242141` I get `-2127232070093227171`.

I can't use strings, arrays, functions. There is another option without define it as string? the output?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class d {

  public static void main(String[] args) {   

    long num = 0;
    long temp = 0L;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = sc.nextLong();

    long place = 1L;
    long output = 0;
    //System.out.print(""+ num%2+ (num%2)%2);
    while(num != 0) {
      temp = num % 2;
      num = num / 2;    

      output += (place*temp);
      place *=10;
    }

    System.out.print(""+output);    
  }
}
```

Comment: I cant use any array. this is the code i need to use, no arrays, no functions and so on.. this is what i need to use. :)

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13249419/edit) and explain in more detail (a) What you want your program to do, and (b) What it is currently doing wrong?

Comment: i think the `output` is overflowing, instead use a string builder for appending the result into a string and then display it

Comment: use output as an String, not as a long if you only want to show it.

Comment: System.out.println( Long.toBinaryString( num )); do the same thing

Comment: @Aubin place it as an answer, hehe.

Comment: Please explain "*I can't use strings, arrays, functions*".

Comment: `System.out.print(""+output)` uses a String and a "function".

Comment: @OfirAttia.. Do yourself a favour. Bet your teacher on doing it without functions. And bet on the priciest thing you can loose, or gain. Your teacher has given you a chance to win something. Make use of that opportunity. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You problem is here

```
  output += (place*temp);
  place *=10;
```

this is producing a number which overflows.

A simple alternative is to create a String instead of generating a number you will convert to a String anyway.

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
while(num != 0) {
  output.append(num & 1);
  num >>>= 1;    
}

System.out.print(output.reverse());
```

or even

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for(long num = sc.netLong(); num != 0; num >>>= 1) 
  output.append(num & 1);

System.out.print(output.reverse());
```

---

**If you want to use no functions except input or output.**

```
long num = 241242141;
int shift = 63;
while (num >>> shift == 0 && shift > 0) shift--;
for (; shift >= 0; shift--)
    System.out.print((num >>> shift) & 1);

// for comparison only
System.out.println("\n"+Long.toBinaryString(num));
```

prints

```
1110011000010001000000011101
1110011000010001000000011101
```

Comment: Why not? StringBuilder is a basic class in `java.lang`

Comment: @Aubin nextLong() and print() are functions which use String and String uses an array, so its impossible as stated. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, you are storing your `Binary Equivalent` in a `long type`, which cannot store such a long values.

You should rather use a `StringBuilder` and append your `remainder - temp` in it.
Then print it in reverse: -

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while(num != 0) {
      temp = num % 2;
      num = num / 2;    

      builder.append(temp);
      output += (place*temp);
      place *=10;
    }

    System.out.println(builder.reverse());
```

If you don't need to use any `methods`, then just use `String Concatenation`, and then a loop to print the string in reverse: -

```
    String builder = "";
    while(num != 0) {
      temp = num % 2;
      num = num / 2;    

      builder += temp;
      output += (place*temp);
      place *=10;
    }

    for (int i = builder.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(builder.charAt(i));
    }
```

But, beware, this will create a large number of `String objects` on `Heap`. Also, here you are using a `charAt` method, that you have to use.

Comment: Well, then without functions, we can't even do anything. To print something we need `System.out.println()` which is a function. Also, OP can't read user input without any functions used from `Scanner` class.

Answer (score 1):

With recursion:

```
public class d {
   static void toBinaryString( long number )
   {
      if( number > 1 ) toBinaryString( number / 2L );
      System.out.print( number % 2L );
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      long num = 241242141L;
      System.out.println( Long.toBinaryString( num ));
      toBinaryString( num );
   }
}
```

The ouput:

```
1110011000010001000000011101
1110011000010001000000011101
```

Comment: +1 Nice Solution, and clearer too :) But beware, you are still using `functions`. ;) :P

Comment: I mean: - `System.out.print()` :D